# Is it possible to extract data from log files with two different date formats?

Tags: bash, datetime, unix, awk

I have two log files.

```
Log1:
Apr 10 02:07:20  Data 1
Apr 11 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
May 12 04:11:09  Data 2

Log 2
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[11/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
```

I want to extract the data specified between the startime and endtime.
I am using the following code. But its not working.

```
log1="$(awk '/LOG_FILE1/{print $NF}' log.conf)"
log2="$(awk '/LOG_FILE2/{print $NF}' log.conf)"
StartTime="$1 $2 $3"
EndTime="$4 $5 $6"
echo $StartTime
echo $EndTime

if [ $log1=log_1.log ]
then
{
for file in $log1;
do     
echo "$file:";    
sort -t' ' -k1,1M -k2,3n $file | sed -n "/$StartTime/,/$EndTime/p";
done
}
fi

if [ $log2=log_2.log ]
then
{
for file in $log2;
do     
echo "$file:";    
sort -n -k 1.5 -k 1.3 -k 1 $file | sed -n "/$StartTime/,/$EndTime/p";
done
}
fi
```

Any my input can either be

```
.filename Apr 10 02:07:20 May 12 04:11:09
```

or

```
.filename [10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] [12/05/16 04:11:09  BST]
```

where filename is the file that contains the above code. I am not getting the result since the data in the log file are in different format? How can I modify the code to extract the data?

where for both the given input, I expect my output to be the following,

```
 Log1:
Apr 10 02:07:20  Data 1
Apr 11 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
May 12 04:11:09  Data 2
Log 2
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[11/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
```

For first input I am getting output like,

```
May 10 04:11:09
May 12 04:11:09
log_1.Log:
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
May 12 04:11:09  Data 
log_2.log:
```

And for the second input my output is like,

```
[10/04/16 02:07:20 BST]
[12/05/16 04:11:09 BST]
log_1.Log:
Apr 10 02:07:20  Data 1
Apr 11 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
May 12 04:11:09  Data 2
log_2.log:
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[11/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
```

How can I modify to get the exact result?

Comment: what do you think `sort -k1,1M` will do to this field `[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST]`?

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @ Ed Morton -Thanks for the answer. And I wish my input will have only three parametes. which are the filename, startime and endtime.

Comment: @ karakfa for sorting data in log2 I am using `$ sort -n -k 1.5 -k 1.3 -k 1 log_2.log` . But how to append two sort commnds ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us your expected output so idk if this outputs what you want or not but this is the way to do what I THINK you want, using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function mthDayTime2secs(mthDayTime,    t, mthNr) {
     split(mthDayTime, t, / /)
     mthNr = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[1])+2)/3
     return mktime(thisYear" "mthNr" "t[2]" "gensub(/:/," ","g",t[3]))
}

function mthDayYearTime2secs(mthDayYearTime,    t) {
     split(mthDayYearTime, t, /[\/ ]/)
     return mktime(thisCent t[3]" "t[1]" "t[2]" "gensub(/:/," ","g",t[4]))
}

function spec2secs(spec,        secs) {
    if (spec ~ /^\[/) {
        secs = mthDayYearTime2secs(gensub(/.(.{17}).*/,"\\1",1,spec))
    }
    else {
        secs = mthDayTime2secs(gensub(/(.{15}).*/,"\\1",1,spec))
    }
    return secs
}

BEGIN {
    thisYear = strftime("%Y")
    thisCent = gensub(/..$/,"",1,thisYear)
    begSecs = spec2secs(begSpec)
    endSecs = spec2secs(endSpec)
}

{ currSecs = spec2secs($0) }
currSecs >= begSecs && currSecs <= endSecs
```

.

```
$ awk -v begSpec="Apr 10 02:07:20" -v endSpec="May 10 04:11:09" -f tst.awk log1 log2
Apr 10 02:07:20  Data 1
Apr 11 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2

$ awk -v begSpec="May 03 02:07:20" -v endSpec="Oct 05 04:11:09" -f tst.awk log1 log2
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[10/04/16 09:07:20  BST] Data 1
```

Comment: Working with date and time is so much painful in awk! Do you know if it is planned to improve that?  Improve means, for example, adding a flexible parse_time() function. Add functions to deal with time spans and time differences etc.. (I'm too lazy/busy to go trough the mailing list atm. Probably you know?)

Comment: No. I tried to get `strptime()` (the standard "parse_time()" function you're looking for) implemented to complement `strftime()` (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.awk/FXrz0VIvz4A/k-ln4T6MEdUJ) but couldn't manage to get that one pushed through. I think the gawk guys were still sulking from when I talked them into impementing `-i inplace` :-). It's not so bad though, usually just 2 or 3 lines in a function. This one's just a bit more work since it's 2 different formats.

Comment: Thanks! Your response was exactly I was hoping you would say! :) Let me add that in Europe it is a real problem to use awk for date/time based tasks because of that.

Comment: Why is it harder in Europe? (I'm Scottish btw and lived in a few other European countries too).

Comment: At least in Germany we are using `DD.MM.YY[YY] [H]H:MM:SS`. Chances are zero to find input data mktime does understand.

Comment: The chances are [close to] zero to find input data mktime() understands in any locale since all it understands is `YYYY [M]M [D]D [H]H [M]M [S]S` (all values blank separated only) so in my experience it **always** takes some massaging to get your timestamp into a format mktime() can use, usually a gensub() or split()+match() if the month is alphabetic. That's why `strptime()` would've been a very useful addition to the time functions - it would've made `mktime()`+formatting redundant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115548/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-ed-morton).